# navigation with known map+rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i created map with rtabmap and saved. but for navigation the saved map not open.
I used rtabmap_ros on a Turtlebot in Gazebo and this is my launch file:

```
<!-- Turtlebot navigation simulation with RTAB-Map -->
<launch>

  <arg name="database_path"     default="rtabmap.db"/>
  <arg name="localization"      default="true"/>

  <!-- Mapping -->
  <group ns="rtabmap">
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen">
      <param name="database_path"       type="string" value="$(arg database_path)"/>
      <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="base_footprint"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"       type="string" value="odom"/>
      <param name="subscribe_laserScan" type="bool"   value="true"/>

      <!-- inputs -->
      <remap from="scan"            to="/scan"/>
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

      <!-- outputs -->
          <remap from="grid_map" to="/map"/> <!-- input for move_base costmap -->

      <!-- RTAB-Map parameters -->
      <param name="RGBD/LocalLoopDetectionSpace" type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="RGBD/OptimizeSlam2D"          type="string" value="true"/>      
      <param name="Kp/MaxDepth"                  type="string" value="4.0"/>
      <param name="Kp/DetectorStrategy"          type="string" value="6"/> <!-- GFTT/BRIEF -->
      <param name="GFTT/MinDistance"             type="string" value="5"/>
      <param name="LccIcp/Type"                  type="string" value="2"/> <!-- ICP 2D -->
      <param name="LccIcp2/CorrespondenceRatio"  type="string" value="0.1"/> 

      <!-- localization mode -->
      <param     if="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes" type="string" value="$(arg localization)"/> 
    </node>
  </group>

  <!-- ******* Navigation - Move Base ******* -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>


  <!-- ******* Visualization of the Turtlebot on Rviz ******* -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/rviz/navigation.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

when launched my launch file the massage was: Requesting the map... but map was not loaded

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280749/navigation-with-known-map+rtabmap/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If rtabmap is not yet localized, it won't publish the map. Move around to see if a loop closure can be found.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-25**:
i moved turtlebot but map is not clear. also when launched my launch file an error is created:

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-25**:
[ERROR] [1516890603.591929995]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-25**:
i thought this error don't allowed the map clear!!!!!!!!!11

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-01-25**:
map is not cleared, can you add screenshots of the problem?

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-26**:
my means is that map isn't load and this error is clear: [ERROR] [1516955866.662140770]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.